# g++ and gcc 4.8 cant find null_ptr?

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-management, null, g++

I read somewhere that gcc 4.6 implemented the c++11 `null_ptr`. I have 4.8 but I can only find `std::nullptr_t` (which doesnt seem to work the same).

What do I need to do/include to use `null_ptr` in g++ 4.8?

Comment: The correct spelling is `nullptr`, with no underscore.

Comment: You might try using the actual reserved word [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr). And so you know, [`std::nullptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) is the *type* of the `nullptr` literal, so I imagine it wouldn't work with how you were likely trying to use it whatsoever.

Comment: @n.m. thank you for pointing this out (without the need to resort to sarcasm....)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::nullptr_t` is the *type*, and it is available in the std namespace.

If you're looking for the *value*, use `nullptr`.

From the standard:

> The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. It is a prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t. [Note: std::nullptr_t is a distinct type that is
>   neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue
>   of this type is a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null
>   pointer value or null member pointer value.]

Comment: And for completeness, `null_ptr` isn't anything.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr `nullptr` is a keyword in C++11.

It's just there, no need to find it.

Answer (score -1):

```
#define null_ptr std::nullptr_t
```

Although I saw it documented as null_ptr as well, so your not crazy on that one.

Note: see technical implementations of harrasments of people by using George Orwell 1984 techniques to disrupt communications of non monopoly corporate profit systems.